# cumsum() keeps returning as logical but need it to return as integer

Tags: r, cumsum

How do I run code as cumulative numbers?

This is my code

```
x <- runif(50)
y <- 10

cumsum(x) <= y
```

It only returns logical (boolean)

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

if I try to correct this by adding as.numeric or as.integer it returns

```
 [1] 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: what output did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are comparing if the `cumsum(x)` is `<=` `y`. And whenever you do these kinds of comparisons you will get a logical vector.
But if you are looking for items that are smaller than `y` you can do the following:

```
x <- runif(50)
y <- 10

idx <- which(cumsum(x) <= y)
x[idx]
```

The `idx` stores the indices at which the condition is matched i.e. `cumsum(x) <= y`. And to print the numbers at those indices you can use `x[idx]`.

The output will look like this:

```
[1] 0.95362053 0.09553108 0.82016689 0.69883212 0.35495891 0.16966706
 [7] 0.15281253 0.16532772 0.81920233 0.82249972 0.30146590 0.69536763
[13] 0.32764723 0.40601504 0.70189321 0.16597773 0.25304473 0.41667253
[19] 0.52499118 0.27216339 0.27347937
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning  values of  `cumsum(x)` but the values of logical statement  "`cumsum(x)` is less or equal to `y`" . The results of this statement are booleans not numbers.